# Toggle Group Box Visibility

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Group Boxes `grpMeter` and `grpTag`. I have to place `grpMeter` over `grpTag`.. both need same location and size..

On button click, I have to make them visible alternately. Is it possible? I tried many times but only 1 group box becomes visible. Maybe because of the overlapping problem. I tried with panel, but the same problem arises. Is there any solution?

```
public void ShowMeter()
{
    grpMeter.Visible = true;
    grpTags.Visible = false;
}

public void ShowTag()
{
    grpTags.Visible = true;
    grpMeter.Visible = false;            
}
```

Comment: Have you added both controls to the parent container?

Comment: not WPF , Yes both group boxes in same container

Comment: Maybe one groupbox is child of the other?

Comment: ya may be.. how i can resolve the problem ??

Comment: Cut groupbox that does not appear, click on its supposed container, then paste it again. give it a try... If it works you can change its `Location` property

Comment: placed groupboxes in such a way they do not overlap,this times works. but i have to make it over other

Comment: One way could be place both the group box inside a panel that they do not overlap each other and set the AutoSizeMode Property of the form to GrowAndShrink. The default value is GrowOnly. This might work.

Comment: Now go to the second groupbox and set `Location` and `Size` exactly as the first groupbox

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Place both group boxes next to each other so that they don't overlap and see if it works then. If you made it work, *don't move the one group box with the mouse*, but select it only and then set the coordinates manually in the Properties list.

That way you can prevent the one group box from accidentially becoming the child of the other group box.

Comment: ok i'll try.. it worked such in a way they do not overlaps.now lwt me change the property

Comment: you can also use arrow keys to move the group box in the correct position.

Comment: This is true, but you're probably quicker simply copy & pasting the other group box's location/size.

Comment: The lesson here is: never use mouse to overlap two container controls! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic inside a button_click event:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grpTags.Visible)
        ShowMeter();
    else
        ShowTag();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grpMeter.Visible = !grpMeter.Visible;
    grpTags.Visible = !grpTags.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but what you are looking for seems like [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx). Then you can put group boxes next to each other and positioning will be handled automatically. This prevents accidentally putting one GroupBox into another or shifting locations. Also provides an easier working at design time.

Comment: He wants to handle visibility not layout.

Comment: I see but for same requirement I often prefer using a flowlayoutpanel. I just make the groupboxes having same size and then show/hide. I don't have to worry about positioning.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. The button Click will toggle visibilty. Also it's important that you set one of the groupboxes as visible and the other one as invisible in your constructor

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //This is important. Set one of them to be Visible and the other one to be invisible
            grpMeter.Visible = false;
            grpTags.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grpMeter.Visible = !grpMeter.Visible;
            grpTags.Visible = !grpTags.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the good way is to use `RadioButton`. Take two Radio buttons and place it inside a groupbox.

Something like this would work:

```
private void rdMeter_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grpMeter.Visible = rdMeter.Checked;
    grpTag.Visible = !rdMeter.Checked;
}

private void rdTag_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grpTag.Visible = rdTag.Checked;
    grpMeter.Visible = !rdTag.Checked;
}
```